# How fast are command block chains?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I’m told a command block chain runs a command every tick meaning twenty commands per second, but I made a chain of 145 command blocks and it ran in under two seconds. Did I make an error? If not, how fast are chain command blocks?

Answer (score 2):

A command block chain executes all the commands inside in a single tick. This means that all 145 commands ran in a single tick.